# can't add youtube video to ckeditor when switching to bbcode

Tags: youtube, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I installed ckeditor and had it set by default to html output, and i managed to add youtube video by clicking flash button and putting youtube link like so: `http://www.youtube.com/v/G6Na--PE9Yo`

now i switched to bbcode, and when i do the same thing it's not working.
i even tried with a YouTube plugin but still not working.

If you know how to fix it I would love to hear.
i have a lead but i don't know how to to this.

when ever someone putting youtube link, I want it to replace it to this syntax:

```
[youtube]http://www.youtube.com/v/G6Na--PE9Yo[/youtube]
```

and on html output it should be:

```
<embed allowfullscreen="true" height="300" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/G6Na--PE9Yo?version=3&amp;color1=0xb1b1b1&amp;color2=0xcfcfcf&amp;feature=player_embedded" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="500"></embed>
```

any way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

I used CKEditor 4.1.2 and BBCode add-on 4.1.3 but I don't think latest versions (4.3) are much different.
All changes you need to do are in the BBCode add-on:

1. YouTube add-on creates iframes but we need to treat them as `youtube` "tag" for bbcode. So add `iframe: 'youtube'` to the `convertMap` in line 30.
2. Now we need to map that "tag" to BBCode tag. Add `youtube: 'youtube'` to the `bbcodeMap` in line 29
3. Now we need to specify what to do with this `youtube` tag. Go to `editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules` (line 637) and add new `else if` for the `youtube` tag:

Code:

```
else if (tagName == 'youtube') {
   element.isEmpty = 0;
   var arr = attributes.src.split('/');
   var ytid = arr[arr.length - 1].split('?')[0];
   element.children = [new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text(ytid)];
   element.attributes.ytheight = attributes.height;
   element.attributes.ytwidth = attributes.width;
}
```

The 1st line is a copy-paste from `img` tag. I'm not sure what it does. Next 3 lines are here to get YouTube id form the `src` attribute and put in between `youtube` tags like this `[youtube]{id}[/youtube]`. It is a bad idea to put a full URL in the YouTube tag, because a user can put any URL there. See conventions: http://www.bbcode.org/reference.php.
This solution is enough in your case but not in mine. I need to transfer width and height too.
So 2 last lines add custom attributes `ytheight` and `ytwidth`. I use the `yt`prefix so that other elements those have `height` or `width` won't get these attributes added to their BBCodes.

4.Go to `var BBCodeWriter = CKEDITOR.tools.createClass` (line 407). And there in `proto:` (line 432) there is a function `attribute : function( name, val )` (line 486) add an `else if` for `ytheight` and one `ytwidth`

Code:

```
else if (name == 'ytwidth') { 
    this.write(' width=', val); 
} else if (name == 'ytheight') {
    this.write(' height=', val);
}
```

You can add more attributes in that way if you want.

The final output:

`[youtube height=315 width=560]0aSCPmabRpM[/youtube]`

P.S. The drawback of this method that all iframes will be treated as YouTube but I don't think you need any other iframes.