# CKeditor BBCODE - custom image tag

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, bbcode

I try to change the image tag in my CKeditor BBCODE. I want this bbcode tag: `[img width={width}]{src}[/img]`

I already saw the following posts: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377246/ckeditor-modify-bbcode-output) post already asked the same question. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904052/cant-add-youtube-video-to-ckeditor-when-switching-to-bbcode) is the way I go at the moment, which was very helpful.

At the moment I changed the BBCode plugin.js as follow:
In `editor.dataProcessor.htmlFilter.addRules` (line 673) I added elements.attributes.imagealt as follow:

```
else if ( tagName == 'img' ) {
                element.isEmpty = 0;

                // Translate smiley (image) to text emotion.
                var src = attributes[ 'data-cke-saved-src' ] || attributes.src, alt = attributes.alt;

                if ( src && src.indexOf( editor.config.smiley_path ) != -1 && alt )
                    return new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( smileyMap[ alt ] );
                else
                    element.children = [ new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( src ) ];
                    // I ADDED THIS LINE
                    attributes.alt &&       (element.attributes.imagealt = attributes.alt);

            }
```

And in the proto under `var BBCodeWriter = CKEDITOR.tools.createClass` (line 407) I changed the following function:

```
attribute: function( name, val ) {
                if ( name == 'option' ) {
                    this.write( '=', val );
                }
                else if (name == 'imagealt') {
                    this.write(' alt=', val);
                }
            }
```

In the Source editor view the BBCode tag is wonderful parsed. But when I switch from source editor to WYSIWYG editor I get the error: candidate is null... Can anybody help me please... I think the problem or reason for the difficulty is, that in var bbcodeMap the img tag is mapped to span?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It is possible that is a bug. You can report it here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues

Comment: @Mateusz Samsel this is not a bug. The BBCode plugin is more of a showcase plugin which presents how to make your own implementation for bbcode. This is not a full bbcode implementation but more of a jump start code. This plugin doesn't support width for images and it is a user responsibility to add it. MaxPerl was asking how to do it.